# Putting JButtons on a stack

Tags: java, null, stack, jbutton, undo

I am making a stat keeping program to practice my GUI skills in Java.

I have a program that records the statistics of basketball players by hitting a JButton under their name. Then it adds the stat to the running total and updates the scoreboard.

It has come time for me to create an undo button.

So, every time an action is performed, I add the source button to a stack of JButtons. There is some casting involved, so it ends up like this:

```
JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
theStack.push(source);
```

Later on, in the `actionPerformed` method I try to call by undo function:

```
if(source.getText().equals("Undo")){
    System.out.println("Undo");
    JButton last = this.theStack.pop();
    System.out.println(last.getText()); //Works fine.
    System.out.println(last.getName()); //Produces a null value.
    int player = Integer.parseInt(last.getName().trim());
    undo(player, last.getText(), activePlayers);
}
```

Why am I getting a null for the name. Eclipse is throwing an exception when it tries to convert the name to an `int` because it is converting a null value. I use the `.getName()` in other parts of the `actionPerformed`, but not here?

My name setting code, done many times in a for loop.

```
output[i][j] = new JButton("Make Two Points");
output[i][j].setName(i + "");
```

The problem in it's simplest form.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Integer> activePlayers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        activePlayers.add(player0Select.getSelectedIndex());
        activePlayers.add(player1Select.getSelectedIndex());
        activePlayers.add(player2Select.getSelectedIndex());
        activePlayers.add(player3Select.getSelectedIndex());
        activePlayers.add(player4Select.getSelectedIndex());

        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
        theStack.push(source);

        if(source.getText().equals("Make Two Points")){
            this.makeTwoPoints(source.getName(), activePlayers); //source.getName() works here.
            System.out.println("Two Points");
        }
        if(source.getText().equals("Undo")){
            System.out.println("Undo");
            JButton last = this.theStack.pop();
            System.out.println(last.getText());
            System.out.println(last.getName()); //last.getName() produces null here.
            int player = Integer.parseInt(last.getName().trim());
            undo(player, last.getText(), activePlayers);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never set the **JButton's** name, and nor should you. Every Component has a name property that can be set via the `setName(...)` method, and if the setter method is never called, then that name is null. But what is the significance of this property? Not much here.

If this were my project, I wouldn't stack JButtons, but rather would stack model objects, or perhaps controls (Actions). Let's not mix our models with our views.

---

**Edit**

For a simple example of what I mean,

You could have a StatAction enum that had your three (or more statistic actions), e.g.,

```
public enum StatAction {
   MAKE_2_PTS("Make Two Points"), MISS_2_PTS("Miss Two Points"), 
   MAKE_3_PTS("Make Three Points");

   private String text;

   private StatAction(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return text;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

}
```

And you could have a Player class that could include a name field as well as a `List<StatAction>`, for example it could have...

```
public class Player {
   private String name;
   private List<StatAction> statActionList = new ArrayList<>();

   // ....

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void addStatAction(StatAction statAction) {
      statActionList.add(statAction);
   }

   public void removeStatAction(StatAction statAction) {
      statActionList.remove(statAction);
   }

   public void removeLastStatAction() {
      if (statActionList.size() > 0) {
         statActionList.remove(statActionList.size() - 1);
      }
   }

   //.....

}
```

And then undo could remove the last StatAction from a Player's list. The display of Stats could then change on the fly via listeners.

Comment: I did set them when I generated them, the name corresponds to the column number, which it turn ties it to an active player in my program.

Comment: @TrevorHutto: the JVM is telling you otherwise, and I believe the JVM. Please show your setting code.

Comment: @TrevorHutto: you'll need to create and post a testable [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to be able to fully understand your problem.

Comment: @TrevorHutto: um,... please re-read the [mcve link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or read it for the first time, because you've not posted anything close to one of these.

Comment: What part are you missing?

Comment: @TrevorHutto: have you read the link? The part that makes it complete, that allows it to be compiled and run by us unaltered. Again, please read the link. It's a complete runnable, but short program that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, I have tried, it must be something intricate.

Comment: @TrevorHutto: It's something in your code, and the more you look for it and try to isolate it, the better your chances of finding it. For more on model separation from view, please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I tried to simplify the code as much as possible.